# Why is dropdown menu disappear when position of its ancestor is set to relative?

Tags: css

When I add a dropdown menu using "position: absolute", I want to add "position: relative" to its nearest ancestor "li.dropDownBtn" and find out that it makes the whole dropdown menue disappear. I have been trying to find out the reason but still haven't got an answer. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks a lot!

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        ul.navBar {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
            overflow: hidden; 
            background-color: #4277f4;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li:hover {
            background-color: #A2AEB3;
        }
        
        /*When this is added, the dropdown disappear
        li.dropDownBtn {
            position: relative
        }
        */

        .dropDownContent {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #7DC9E3;
            width: 150px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            text-decoration: none;
            
        }
        .dropDownContent a {
            color: white;
            display: block;

        }
        .dropDownContent a:hover{
            background-color: #4A96B0;
        }


        li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul class="navBar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropDownBtn"><a href="#">Products</a>
            <div class="dropDownContent">
                <a href="#">Product1</a>
                <a href="#">Product2</a>
                <a href="#">Product3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njwemcck/4/) for this navigation bar page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` on the main menu is keeping the submenu from showing. I'm assuming you're using that to clear the floats in your nav menu, so added a `.clearfix` with a different technique that doesn't use `overflow: hidden` and removed `overflow: hidden` from your menu's CSS

```css
ul.navBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #4277f4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: #A2AEB3;
}

li.dropDownBtn {
  position: relative;
}

.dropDownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #7DC9E3;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.dropDownContent a {
    color: white;
    display: block;

}
.dropDownContent a:hover{
    background-color: #4A96B0;
}


li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
    display: block;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="navBar clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropDownBtn"><a href="#">Products</a>
            <div class="dropDownContent">
                <a href="#">Product1</a>
                <a href="#">Product2</a>
                <a href="#">Product3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: You have perfectly solved my puzzle! I'll go find out more information about .clearfix now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set a height for ul.navBar and take out overflow hidden

```
ul.navBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #4277f4;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:55px;
}
```

Comment: It works but has one minor problem: how can I make sure the height of this "ul.navBar" is just enough to contain the "li" elements? For example, if it's "55px" as you mentioned, it would leave a small space underneath each "li" box when it is hovered.

Comment: Just tweak it. Try with 54px, 53px etc... until it's right.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have this setting:

```
.dropDownContent {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
etc.
```

Which means the dropdown is not displayed by default (which usually is the desired function...).

And then you have this rule, which makes it visible when you hover its `li` parent:

```
li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
  display: block;
}
```

That's the way CSS dropdown menus work, what do you not like about it?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what I'm asking here.